# JSON.parse() specifically the operators

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Can someone explain why when I try to use JSON.parse() on the operators "+", "-", "*", "/" it returns:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token +
SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
```

I am passing a string which is valid but it will not return the operator as itself. There is nothing in the documentation that would explain why this is invalid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit for clarity*

In the documentation, the cases below are all valid. They are arbitrary strings being passed to JSON.parse(). You can verify these examples in your console. My question is why passing an operator as a string will not return the operator.

```
JSON.parse('{}');              // {}
JSON.parse('true');            // true
JSON.parse('"foo"');           // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null');            // null
```

Comment: JSON has a very specific syntax, just like any other data description format, e.g. XML. `"+"` is not valid JSON. It would not be valid XML either. Not sure what you expect? Here is the complete syntax: http://json.org/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `JSON.parse` is for parsing [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), not arbitrary JavaScript. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the JSON you can provide?

Comment: http://json.org/ <-- the spec

Comment: Those are *not* arbitrary values. `JSON.parse('asdasd');` is arbitrary but is not valid either.  All your examples are valid JSON. Valid constructs are objects: `{}`, arrays: `[]`, numbers: `42`, strings: `"foo"`, null: `null`, true: `true`, false: `false`. That's it. That's how JSON is defined.

Comment: The link you posted says: *"The string to parse as JSON. See the [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) object for a description of JSON syntax."*.  I suggest you follow the link to learn more about the syntax.

Comment: You ask _why passing an operator as a string will not return the operator._ What does it mean to "return the operator"? An operator is not a type of data that can be represented in JSON. It only supports numbers, strings, objects, arrays, and booleans.

Comment: Even in JavaScript (and most other languages for that matter) you cannot "return" an operator. Only *values* can be returned.

Comment: Maybe this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, strings need to be in double quotes. So if you want a JSON string that contains an operator, it needs to be quoted.

```js
var json = '"+"';
var result = JSON.parse(json);
alert(result);
```

This will alert `+`.

The single quotes are for the Javascript literal, the double quotes are part of the JSON syntax.

Comment: Based on your code  `2 + result + 2` will return the string `"2+2"`. It's not an operator. It's still a string and has not been parsed.

Comment: @GeraldAnekwe: Of course. JSON is a **data description format**. It's not a programming language. It doesn't have operators.

Comment: @GeraldAnekwe `JSON.parse` isn't for parsing Javascript expressions, it's for parsing JSON data.

Comment: This is simply not true. The documentation passed a plain empty object as a string and it returns an object. `JSON.parse('{}');              // {}`

Comment: That's valid JSON for an object with no properties.

Comment: What Javascript value do you expect `JSON.parse('2 + 2')` to return?

Comment: @GeraldAnekwe: Again, JSON is a data description format. `{"key": value}` is valid JSON and describes a mapping. The purpose of `JSON.parse` is to convert the description into native data types. `{...}` naturally maps to objects in JavaScript. In Python it would map to dictionaries. Similarly, `null` is converted to `null` in JavaScript but  `None` in Python. You really have the wrong idea what JSON is, and if you keep insisting that what we say is wrong, then you cannot be helped. JSON has the same purpose as XML, YAML and CSV is. Those are not programming languages.

Comment: @GeraldAnekwe You're confused because the syntax of JSON happens to be patterned after Javascript syntax. But it's only the syntax of **literal** objects, not arbitrary expressions. And it's only a subset (e.g. Javascript allows either single or double quotes around strings, JSON only allows double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

JSON it's a string that contains key value pairs. `JSON.parse()` it's a function that will return object with properties named with key, and it mean that you can't use +, -, /, * as name for object property. That's why you receive this error.

Comment: *"JSON.parse() it's a function that will return object with properties named with key"* No. It will return the corresponding value for the JSON value that was passed in.

Comment: But, if i type valid json: `JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}')` i'll receive: `Object {foo: "bar"}`... i just try say that +, - etc not good for object property name...

Comment: Yes, but if you type `JSON.parse('"foo"')` then you get `"foo"`, not an object.

Comment: Yes! of course) You're right... i usually meet this error when i have something bad in key... that's why i decided that question exactly about it...

Answer (score 0):

Operators are not valid json. `JSON.parse` is for converting a json formatted string into corressponding javascript types and objects. You are looking for  `eval`. `eval` executes a string as if it were javascript code.

[Information on `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

[Information on valid `json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)